# React Native transparent, clipping border radius?

Tags: react-native, styling

Hello guys I want to make a transparent border radius so I can achieve

[image]

This style. (The icons border is clipping the box)

Comment: I know you can do this with box-shadow in normal css, but don't know how it will work with react-native as shadows doesn't work on android. You might want to consider having the box as a picture or vector graphic (png/svg).

Comment: Yeah I tried SVG, but unfortunately react-native-svg didn't implemented the Mask yet :/

Comment: You ever found a solution?

Comment: Well, the what I did was basically what @howtopythonpls suggested. I created the Body as an SVG (react native svg) and just draw the circle positioned to the right position. But as far as I know, since my problem react native svg already implemented the Mask and Clip functionality. (You could also have the very top of the Widget as an SVG and the bottom part as your everyday component)